# Deleting haccessmyemail.co from my computer

Tags: windows-10

"haccessmyemail.co" is on my computer (Windows 10 OS) and I can't get it off.  I do not have Chrome or Mozilla Firefox downloaded on the computer

Comment: What is hasaccessmymail.co? Is it a virus? A program? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it is.  Just that it is unwanted and annoying.  I have gone into every application I have on the computer to find when and where it was loaded onto the computer to uninstall it.  But there is no informational evidence as to how it got on the computer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1080642)